# UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте делаю API для заметок. При создании User и добавлении email и password (нужны только эти поля) сначала все хорошо и все без ошибок:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при последующем добавлении выходит ошибка: `

```
IntegrityError at /api/v1/user/
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/
Django Version: 5.0
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
Exception Location: E:\Phyton\api\test2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during:  note.views.UserAPIList
Python Executable:  E:\Phyton\api\test2\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:    
['E:\\Phyton\\api\\test2\\keeps',
 'C:\\Users\\glebn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\glebn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\glebn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\glebn\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'E:\\Phyton\\api\\test2\\venv',
 'E:\\Phyton\\api\\test2\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 29 Dec 2023 18:28:26 +0300
```

`

Что делать?

Файл views: `

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserAPIList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

`

файл serializer:
`

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Note
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

`

файл models:
`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Без названия')
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, default='Пусто')
    time_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`

файл urls:
`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/user/', UserAPIList.as_view())
]
```

`

Comment: Самое быстрое и простое - при создании пользователя передавать уникальный username. В БД ограничение, что должен быть уникальный username в таблице

Comment: Получилось, просто передал username. Пускай будет. Но было бы лучше без него

Comment: На этот случай у Джанго есть описание в документации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: Спасибо большое!